# Некорректное отображение строк в CheckedListBox. C#

Tags: c#, строки, closedxml

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Приложение Win Forms. Есть документ Excel следующего вида:
[image: Документ]

Из каждой строки, начиная с 10-ой, берутся значения ячеек 2, 3 и 4 и складываются в одну строку.  Все эти строки сохраняются в лист, значениями которого нужно заполнить checkedListBox. Я делал вот так:

```
for_check.Add(rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 2).Value.ToString() +
" " + rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 3).Value.ToString() + 
" " + rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 4).Value.ToString());
```

где `for_check` - собственно лист, в который всё добавляем,
`i` - итератор цикла и номер строки.

Проблема в следующем: при выводе на экран строк в checkedListBox-е некоторые из них выводятся не полностью, а именно не хватает последней части:[image: Вид в листбоксе]
В процессе решения выяснил, что некоторые значения ячеек складываются в целую строку не так, как остальные, а с переносом на новую строку, как раз перед последней частью:[image: Вывод]
Каким образом можно убрать этот перенос? Или просто сделать правильное отображение данных. Ковырялся в свойствах CheckedListBox-a - ничего не дало. Думаю, что нужно указывать строке при сборке игнорировать спец. символы, но их и так вроде бы нет. Так же проверял исходный Excel-файл, игрался с форматом ячеек - тоже не помогло.

Comment: `(rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 2).Value.ToString() + " " + rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 3).Value.ToString() + " " + rez_doc.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, 4).Value.ToString()).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, но к сожалению я пробовал этот вариант, результат такой же. Значение из 4-ой ячейки в некоторых случаях всё так же уплывает на новую строку

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но при изменении порядка складывания значений ячеек в строку (не 2-3-4, а, например, 4-2-3) проблема исчезает. Для моей задачи порядок не принципиален, по этому оставил так. Другого решения, к сожалению, не нашел.